# Jquery Corners produces a white background. I need transparent background corners

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im creating a navigation window with tabs round cornered. im trying to do this but jquery corner produces a white background ar corners. How can we overcome that problem. here is the snapshow of my navigation bar

http://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/3858299131/

Comment: It doesn't work if the parent node's background is an image or using a gradient.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is obsolete, and the [tag:corners] is undergoing burnination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set the color with cc:

```
$("myDiv").corner("cc:#fff round 20px");
```

Comment: You must be using a different plugin, then.

Comment: No, Im using Jquery.corners.js

Comment: You might be using an older version.... Get the latest here:  http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/  There's a demo page with colored corners, so I know this works.

Comment: I tried by downloading your updated corners. still its not working @will

Comment: Sorry, Its Working, Thanks +1 Vote

Comment: This doesn't work if you have the div ehind a gradient which changes colors.  Colors won't match up.